# Обращение одного jFrame к элиментам другого jFrame

Tags: java

Здравствуйте, есть ли возможность обращаться с одного **jFrame** к элементам другого **jFrame**?.

Если есть тогда к примеру у меня есть **jFrame1** *(в этом находится кнопка)* и **jFrame2** *(в этом есть текстовое поле)*. 
Как реализовать что-бы при нажатии на кнопку в текстовом поле вывелось "Hello"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Конечно, любой класс может обращаться к членам любого класса. Для этого методы и поля, к которым происходит обращение извне пакета, должны быть описаны с ключевым словом `public`. Если классы находятся в одном пакете, то такие члены могут быть оставлены без указания области видимости (т. н. "default access level", уровень доступности по умолчанию, или по другому "package access"). Почитайте подробнее на https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html или в русскоязычной литературе о доступе к членам классов. По реализации взаимодействия между окнами есть более-менее общепринятые практики. Обычно с элементом, который должен реагировать на события системы (в вашем случае кнопка, реагирующая на нажатие) связывается т. наз. "слушатель" (listener) - это объект, в котором содержится метод, вызываемый системой при нажатии кнопки. Этот метод может установить текст в другой форме, если у соотв. элемента этой другой формы достаточный уровень доступности. Что-то типа такого:

```
...
Button button = new Button("Button");  // Создаете кнопку
button.addActionListener(buttonListener); // Привязываете слушатель
...

// отдельное поле - Слушатель - объект анонимного класса, 
// производного от  ActionListener 
ActionListener buttonListener = new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    // переопределяем метод, который будет вызван при нажатии кнопки,
    // чтобы он делал, что нам надо
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        // Устанавливаем текст во второй форме
        jframe2.ourText.setText("Кнопка нажата");
    }
}
```

Другая форма пр иэтом должна содержать такое описание:

```
public Text ourText = ...
```

Есть более изящные способы записать то же самое, но в такой форме (на мой взгляд) принцип виден наиболее отчетливо.

В большенстве случаев, однако, лучше бывает не делать публичными элементы формы, а сделать в ней специальные публичные методы для управления формой. Это позволит в будущем легче изменить дизайн формы и/или ее функциональность, не меняя всю остальную программу.
Напр. так:

```
// Слушатель:   
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    jframe2.setImportantText("Кнопка нажата"); // Вызов метода 
}
...
// Вторая форма: 
private Text ourText = ... // Элемент недоступен извне
....
public void setImportantText(String text) { // Метод доступа (сеттер)
    // Тут можно делать что-нибудь --
    // напр, проверить или изменить текст 
    ourText.setText(modifiedText);
    // И можно сделать еще что-нибудь -- 
    // перевести на китайский и произнести вслух
}
```

Об этом подробнее можно прочитать тут https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html или в русской литературе про события и слушатели.